# Non-slanted vector sign for numbers

Tags: vector

I recently begun to worry about using `\vec` on numbers. The arrow is both off-center and slanted, which only works for italics. Is there a simple command to typeset number vectors properly?

```
$\vec{x}$ % ok
$\vec{0}$ % not ok
```

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It is usually best to post a complete compilable document, in this case that would remove any ambiguity about which fonts you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are prepared to compile with lualatex then you can use the `unicode-math` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \vec x \)

\( \vec 0 \)
\end{document}
```

Depending on your text font, in `pdflatex` you could use the package `MnSymbol`, this fits with Minion Pro and related fonts.

Answer (score 5):

Using the package `esvect`, you get the new command `\vv{}`, which not only solves your problem of slanted arrow, but can also be used for vectors above multiple letters. The package takes a letter (from a to h) as an option to customize the arrow type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv{0}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Preview of the use of the esvect package]